# Attunity Replicate sample installation

Tags: replication, attunity

I am trying to install Attunity Replicate into a local virtual machine with CentOS 7 on it. I can see that it is running - using 'ps -ef | grep repctl', and I know that the 3552 port is open in the firewall, and the host is visible (using 'nc -zv  3552').

But I cannot connect my UI browser to Attunity server using 'https://:/AttunityReplicate' - the Safari answers that 'Safari can't open the page XXX becauseSafari cannot establish a secure connection to the server...', and Chrome answers with 'ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT' error...

Any hints - what and where should I configure in the Attunity Server to resolve the security issue, please?

Kind regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

1. On the Linux server where you installed Replicate Express, cd into /opt/Attunity/replicate/bin (this is the default location) and run the following command:

   cd /opt/attunity/replicate/bin 
   source arep_login.sh
   ./repctl SETSERVERPASSWORD 
   ./arep.ctl stop
   ./arep.ctl start
2. Ensure that your Linux server allows inbound TCP connections on port 3552
3. Open your browser and try to connect to the following URL: https://:3552/attunityreplicate replacing  with the DNS name or IP address of the Linux Server where Replicate is installed.
4. When prompted, enter the Username: Admin and Password from Step 1.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to allow the webpage on Chrome:
1- On your computer, open Chrome.
2- On the page where you see a warning, click Details.
3- Click Visit this unsafe site.
4- The page will load.

Reference: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en